# DataGridView hides the scroll bars after populating with async

Tags: c#, asynchronous, datagridview, task

In my form, I have 4 datagrid separated using tab control.

When I try to populate it with async task, the scrollbars are gone.

here's my code

```
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            PopulateHistoryAll(items);
            PopulateHistoryParkerIn(parkerIn);
            PopulateHistoryParkerOut(parkerOut);
            PopulateHistoryMonthlyIn(monthlyIn);
            PopulateHistoryMonthlyOut(monthlyOut);
        });
```

I tried to use this code

```
        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            //DataGridview Refreshment
            dgParkerIn.Enabled = true;
            dgParkerIn.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Both;
        });
```

but its not working.

Please help me, thank you :)

Comment: Need to see the code of the Populate* methods

Comment: Personally I would have those Populate* methods fill 5 datatables, then assign them to each relevant datagridview.DataSource as and when (via an invoke if you do it as part of the asynchronous work) and leave the scrollbars property alone. Never had a datagridview fail to show its scrollbars as needed when using this simple route of populating them

Answer (score 0):

Here's my code for populate tables. they are all the same

```
    private void PopulateHistoryAll(IEnumerable<HistoryModel> items)
    {
        dgHistoryAll.Rows.Clear();
        if (items.Count() > 0)
            dgHistoryAll.Rows.Add(items.Count());

        var row = 0;
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            dgHistoryAll[dtlAllRow.Index, row].Value = row + 1;
            dgHistoryAll[dtlAllTransitId.Index, row].Value = item.Id;
            dgHistoryAll[dtlAllTerminal.Index, row].Value = item.Terminal;
            dgHistoryAll[dtlAllORNo.Index, row].Value = item.ORNumber;
            dgHistoryAll[dtlAllPlateNo.Index, row].Value = item.PlateNo;
            dgHistoryAll[dtlAllTicketNo.Index, row].Value = item.TicketNumber;
            dgHistoryAll[dtlAllDateTimeIn.Index, row].Value = item.TimeIn;
            dgHistoryAll[dtlAllDateTimeOut.Index, row].Value = item.TimeOut;
            dgHistoryAll[dtlAllDurationOfStay.Index, row].Value = item.Duration;
            dgHistoryAll[dtlAllRatesName.Index, row].Value = item.RateName;
            dgHistoryAll[dtlAllCoupon.Index, row].Value = item.Coupon;
            dgHistoryAll[dtlAllMonthlyRFID.Index, row].Value = item.MonthlyRFID;
            dgHistoryAll[dtlAllMonthlyName.Index, row].Value = item.MonthlyName;
            row++;
        }
        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            dgHistoryAll.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Both; 
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution.

Though this is odd...

I tried to delete the datagrid, and add create another one and then....

it works, idk why.